# How to pass SSH keys as getopt parameters to docker build

Tags: bash, docker, shell, getopt

I have a build function written in bash that is using `getopt` to take parameters. I'm using it to build docker projects. Because projects' build args are differentiating a lot, I decided to take build arguments as `getopt` parameter. It works fine, it works in production setup for a while so no problem in general functioning. I've integrated it to all my repos, tests are successful except one repo which is taking SSH keys as build arguments.

In image-builder function, parameters are being taken like this,

```
TEMP_BUILD=$(getopt -o hw:v:b:s:d: --longoptions help,working-dir:,version-tag:,build-number:,service-name:,docker-build-arguments: -- "$@")

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; 
then
    echo "Failed to parse options...exiting." >&2 ; 
    exit 1;
fi

eval set -- "$TEMP_BUILD"

# extract options and their arguments into variables.
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -h|--help)
                HELP="true" ; shift ;;
        -w|--working-dir)
            case "$2" in
                "") WORKING_DIR='' ; shift 2 ;;
                *) WORKING_DIR=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
            esac ;;
        -v|--version-tag)
            case "$2" in
                "") VERSION_TAG='' ; shift 2 ;;
                *) VERSION_TAG=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
            esac ;;
        -b|--build-number)
            case "$2" in
                "") BUILD_NUMBER='' ; shift 2 ;;
                *) BUILD_NUMBER=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
            esac ;;
        -s|--service-name)
            case "$2" in
                "") SERVICE_NAME='' ; shift 2 ;;
                *) SERVICE_NAME=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
            esac ;;
        -d|--docker-build-arguments)
            case "$2" in
                "") DOCKER_BUILD_ARGUMENTS='' ; shift 2 ;;
                *) DOCKER_BUILD_ARGUMENTS=$2 ; shift 2 ;;
            esac ;;
            --) shift ; break ;;
        *) echo "Invalid Parameter!" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
```

Normally I'm running the function as

```
image-builder --working-dir "$(pwd)" --version-tag "tag" --build-number "xx" --service-name "service" --docker-build-arguments "--build-arg ARG1=argument-1 --build-arg ARG2=argument-2"
```

And the docker build line in the script is running like this;

`docker build -t $SERVICE_NAME:$VERSION_TAG.$BUILD_NUMBER -f $WORKING_DIR/Dockerfile .`

Until here, I explained my setup, here is my problem,

As I said, a project is requiring **SSH keys** to be passed in `docker build`, So when I try

`image-builder --working-dir "$(pwd)" --version-tag "tag" --build-number "xx" --service-name "service" --docker-build-arguments "--build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa) --build-arg SSH_PUBLIC_KEY=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"`

It's giving `bad flag syntax: -----END`

There are tons of issues about this error, and generally double quoting the keys is suggested. When I try to double quote key variables like below,

`image-builder --working-dir "$(pwd)" --version-tag "tag" --build-number "xx" --service-name "service" --docker-build-arguments "--build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" --build-arg SSH_PUBLIC_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)""`

The function is recognizing some part of the key as parameter and returning
`getopt: unrecognized option '-----END'` error.

I even tried to convert my keys to base64 as it's suggested in another issue, but also returned an error because during build phase, the project is trying to pull other repositories from bitbucket and bitbucket and bitbucket returning `permission denied` for SSH key because of the `bad format`.

I'm a little bit stuck in this point about what to do,

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do the private keys need to be included in the finished image, or do you just need them during the image build process? In the latter case, you might want to investigate [docker build secrets](https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/build-secrets-and-ssh-forwarding-in-docker-18-09-ae8161d066).

Comment: @larsks it will be needed, this application is constantly checking other repos and fetch their tags, descriptions, history etc. It's an inner application. Also I'm afraid I can't use docker secrets because of the general structure and standardization issues. Best option is to make this work somehow :/

Answer (score 0):

You can't double quote something using the same type of quote, if you write:

```
image-builder "--build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)""
```

You have effectively three contatenated strings:

- `"--build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="`
- `$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)`
- `""`

As you can see, your `cat` expansion is still unquoted. You could try writing:

```
image-builder "--build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY='$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)'"
```

Note the use of *single* quotes (`'`) on the inner expression. But you may also want to consider avoiding some of the quoting issues by adding an explicit argument to your `image-builder` script that would take the *path* to a secret key file, and then generate the appopriate `--build-arg` command in the script.  So you would call it like:

```
image-builder --ssh-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And inside your script you would do something like:

```
docker build ... --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY)"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding,  when I tried this with a single quote sth like`image-builder --working-dir "$(pwd)" --version-tag "tag" --build-number "xx" --service-name "service" --docker-build-arguments "--build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY='$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)' --build-arg SSH_PUBLIC_KEY='$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)'", as you said inner part is consisting the ' and it's still giving the `bad flag syntax: -----END` error. Is using double quote in  docker build arguments mandatory to be able to process SSH Keys?

Comment: It has nothing to do with ssh keys in particular; it has to do with passing arguments that contain whitespace through multiple levels of shell de-quoting. I think the solution I suggested here re: adding an explicit argument for ssh keys will make things much easier.

Comment: Yes it's looks more appealing and I will try it, Thank you very much :)